# Spring Security causing problems when doing unit tests on REST controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

So basically i am doing some unit tests on my rest controller, before using spring security everything was working smoothly, after adding it and setting the spring security to my mockmvc, it's always returning a 302 and nothing else, after tinkering with my code and the browser i found out that after logging in, i am indeed receiving a 302 code which is as intended because of the redirection, it seems that the `loginProcessingUrl` in my configuration is causing this:

My spring security configuration:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/showMyLoginPage")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticateTheUser")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .logoutUrl("/logoutUser")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
```

The REST method i am testing:

```
    @GetMapping(path = "/list/getProducts")
    public String getProducts()
    {
        List<Product> products = productService.getProducts();
        return gson.toJson(products);
    }
```

And finally my test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/test/java/resources/ProductCRUD-servlet.xml")
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ProductControllerTest
{

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext context;

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductRestController productRestController;

    @Mock
    private ProductService productService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getAllProductsTest() throws Exception
    {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(new Product("4532", 123, "Product test", "test"));
        Mockito.when(productService.getProducts())
                .thenReturn(products);
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/product/list/getProducts"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk)
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("\"productId\":\"4534\"")));    
    }
```

So what is happening is, even though my website is working and i am retrieving my json, the login process is messing up my test somehow.

[image]

Even if i set my test status code to 302 instead of 200, it isn't returning anything.

```
Expected :a string containing "\"productId\":\"4534\""
Actual   :""
```

TLDR:
When testing my REST api which is protected by spring security, i am not able to reach the api from the tests.

Comment: If you want to (frontend-) integration test the controller, I'd go [`@WithMockUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser). If you want to test the security config, assert for a 403/redirect (without mock/with forbidden/anonymous user).

Comment: @xerx593 Correct, if you want add this as an answer.

Comment: welcome & thank you, sorry it will be short! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spring security integration tests, we can use `@WithMockUser` as the methods proposed by [11. Testing Method Security (current spring-security guide)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/test-method.html).

However it is also good to test "resticted scenarios", where we would provide  unauthorized/omit/anonymous user, and assert for the according reactions (exceptions, http codes, redirects,...).